# IstandaloneCodeEditor.addOverlayWidget()

Tags: monaco-editor

I have to add an overlay widget on Monaco editor at a particular position.From Docs, I came to know that there is a method in IStandaloneCodeEditor call addOverlayWidget to do this.But I don't know how to pass position as a parameter to this method.Does anyone know please help me by giving some examples using the above mentioned function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the `addOverlayWidget` must create the html element by the interface method `getDomNode` - when creating the dom node/element, set the position using its style or class attributes.

see here https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-listening-to-mouse-events